# Auto-injection custom ErrorHandler in spring-rabbitmq

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection, spring-integration, spring-rabbit

We know that we can inject custom message converter:

```
@Bean
MessageConverter messageConverter(){
   return new CustomMessageConverter();
}
```

However in case of `ErrorHandler` it doesn't work. Why ?  Can I conclude it from code in any way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's true. Spring Boot's `RabbitAnnotationDrivenConfiguration` doesn't support that injection.

You have to declare your own `SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory` `@Bean` and supply desired `ErrorHandler` injection, as well as all other required options, including `MessageConverter`.

Note that overriding out-of-the-box bean you should specify your own one with the `rabbitListenerContainerFactory` name to meet condition:

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = "rabbitListenerContainerFactory")
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory(
```

Comment: Thanks, I did exactly as you wrote. Own Container, so all configuration. In this case MessageConverter, ErrorHandler can be non-bean, however I annotated it as bean to avoid calling new operator. Is it good practice ?  And second issue: I checked it that `ErrorHandler` is not auto-injected experimentally - how should I have checked it in code ?

Comment: What do you mean "in code"? I show you `RabbitAnnotationDrivenConfiguration` that is a place where everything is configured by default on the matter

Comment: Do you mean that that: `rabbitListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer` has no instruction:   `configurer.setErrorHandler(this.errorHandler.getIfUnique());` ??

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean